# self.navigationController is 'null' even after embed in a navigationcontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, pushviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I want to add a `navigationcontroller` to an existing `viewcontroller` which is created using `storyboard`, i have embed it in a navigation controller, but the code for navigating (shown below) is not working even after embed in the navigation controller:

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    EditProfileViewController *nextViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EPVController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
```

When i have tried to log `self.navigationController`, it shows `null`.

> **Update**: It is fine when i am trying with `presentViewcontroller` , but i
>   want to push the `viewcontroller` with `navigationController`.

I am struggling with this for two days,Please help.

Comment: you set this "EPVController" id in storyboard?

Comment: @DharmeshDhorajiya: yes

Comment: What kind of controller is `self` and how do you create it?

Comment: @PhillipMills: it is created via storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If self is a subclass of UINavigationController, you do not need to refer to the navigationController property. (Note that this won't work if EditProfileViewController is also a subclass of UINavigationController, as you can't push a UINavigationController inside a UINavigationController).

```
EditProfileViewController *nextViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EPVController"];
[self pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
```

Otherwise, if you don't have a pre-existing navigation controller

```
EditProfileViewController *nextViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EPVController"];
[self presentViewController:nextViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: It is ok to present a viewController, issue comes when i am trying to push. and i want to push and pop.